# Find the vector projection and component perpendicular

Tags: vectors

Question: If vector $a = <2,3,5>$ and vector $b = <2,-2,-1>$, find the vector projection of b onto a and hence find the component of b perpendicular to a.

I found the vector projection of b onto a using the vector projection formula which is (-7/38)<2,3,5>.

Do I find the component of b perpendicular to a by using vector b - vector projection? Would this be <2,-2,-1> - (-7/38)<2,3,5>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vector Projection = $\mbox{proj}_{a}b=\dfrac{a\cdot b}{|a|^2}a=\dfrac{\langle2,3,5\rangle\langle2,-2,-1\rangle}{38}(2)$

The component of b perpendicular to a is $b-\mbox{proj}_{a}b$

Comment: Under "vector projection" in the answer why is it "(2)" at the end and not (2,3,5)?